# Possible to append result of php conditional into div?

Tags: php, jquery, append, conditional-statements, appendto

I have this php code:

```
<?php if ( $hide_all_info == 0 ) { ?> 
    <span class="film_meta_wrap">
        <div class="film_meta_title"><?php echo the_title(); ?></div>
        <div class="film_meta_text"><?php echo $film_meta_info; ?></div>
    </span>
<?php } elseif ( $hide_all_info == 1 ) { ?>
    <span class="film_meta_wrap"></span>
<?php } ?>
```

I need to move/append the result of that `if` statement into an existing div *within the current loop item* like so:

```
jQuery( ".film_meta_wrap" ).appendTo( ".arve-embed-container" );
```

My current result is as expected, but not what I need to do: all of the code is appended regardless of said `if` statement, and it also places the same spans in every loop item (ie. doesn't honor the loop it resides within for individual posts). Does that make sense? How would I get the jQuery to append the one span *after* the php variables and conditionals are parsed and populated. And for each loop item. Is it even possible? Ajax would be an acceptable solution, just don't know how that would work.

EDIT** I modified the suggested code to also append the `elseif` result:

```
<?php if ( $hide_all_info == 0 ) { ?>

    <script>
    var _html = '<span class="film_meta_wrap">'
    +'<div class="film_meta_title"><?php echo the_title(); ?></div>'
    +'<div class="film_meta_text"><?php echo $film_meta_info; ?></div>'
    +'</span>';
    jQuery('.arve-embed-container').append(_html);
    </script>

<?php } elseif ( $hide_all_info == 1 ) { ?>

    <script>
    var _html = '<span class="film_meta_wrap"></span>';
    jQuery('.arve-embed-container').append(_html);
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<?php if ( $hide_all_info == 0 ) {

    echo '<script>';
    $innerHtml = '<span class="film_meta_wrap">
                    <div class="film_meta_title">'.the_title().'</div>
                    <div class="film_meta_text">'.$film_meta_info.'</div>
                </span>';
    echo 'jQuery(function(){ jQuery(".arve-embed-container").append('.$innerHtml.') });';
    echo '</script>'

} elseif ( $hide_all_info == 1 ) { ?>
    <span class="film_meta_wrap"></span>
<?php } ?>
```

**Finally made it work**

Do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- jQuery should be decalred on the top --->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="arve-embed-container">

    </div>

    <?php 
    $hide_all_info = 0;
    if ( $hide_all_info == 0 ) {
    $innerHtml = '<span class="film_meta_wrap">
                    <div class="film_meta_title">Yo</div>
                    <div class="film_meta_text">Wassup</div>
                </span>';
    echo '<script>';
    echo '$(function(){ $(".arve-embed-container").append(\''.str_replace("\n", "", $innerHtml).'\') });';
    echo '</script>';

    } elseif ( $hide_all_info == 1 ) { ?>
        <span class="film_meta_wrap"></span>
    <?php } ?>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I modified your code to include another `.append()` for the `elseif` result in my code above, but it's still not working. Test site is here if you want to take a look: http://davejmoz.com/test

Comment: You've got sort of a mess of single and double quotes in there, but still didn't work after I fixed those.

Comment: That latest edit actually made all of the content disappear. Was better before.

Comment: I'm using this in Wordpress so I already have jQuery enqueued. And my `$hide_all_info` variable pulls in dynamic post meta, so I can't just set it to 0. If you care to look at the working test site, it's here: http://davejmoz.com/test

Comment: That was just a sample variable i used.. You tried running the updated code?

Comment: Yea, it didn't work on my test site. Thanks for trying though.